# ActiveLdap find users by attribute

Tags: ruby, ldap

I'm trying to search for users with particular attribute values with ActiveLdap, but it is sending some odd queries to the server. I have it set up like this:

```
class Ldapuser < ActiveLdap::Base
    ldap_mapping :dn_attribute => 'uid',
                 :prefix => 'ou=People',
                 :classes => ['top', 'inetOrgPerson']
end
```

And then try to find students with a particular major:

```
Ldapuser.all(
        :attribute => 'studentMajor', :value => 'CHEM',
        :attribute => 'primaryAffiliation', :value => 'student',
        :attribute => 'organizationalStatus', :value => 'active').each {|user|
    # process the user...
}
```

When I run this, it never reaches the inner block where it would process a user, and I have to kill the program. Tcpdump shows three searches that were performed:

- searchRequest(1) "" baseObject - which gave 0 results.
- searchRequest(2) "cn=schema" baseObject - which gave 115 results.
- searchRequest(3) "ou=people,dc=myedu,dc=edu" wholeSubtree - which takes too long so I interrupt it.

My expectation is that it would do a single query and quickly get about 20 results, which is what I get when using ldapsearch from the command line:

```
ldapsearch -x '(&(studentMajor=CHEM)(primaryAffiliation=student)
        (organizationalStatus=active))'
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear from the documentation that multiple attribute name-value pairs are recognized by .all(), which is a synonym for find(:all, ...), and the behaviour you are seeing agrees. It seems to be searching on only the first pair, or possibly any one pair: hence the long search time. You need to use the :filter option, from what I can gather quickly.